# Laravel 9 & Dompdf: Too few arguments to function Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct(), 0 passed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I'm working with Laravel 9 and Dompdf to generate some pdf files from the information provided on the form, so I tried this:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

And then register it at `config.php`:

```
'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::class,
 ])->toArray(),

'providers' => [
        Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
 ],
```

Then in the Controller:

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

class ResumeController extends Controller
{
    public function generate(Request $request)
    {
        // Generate HTML for the resume using the form data
        $html = '<h1>' . $request->input('name') . '</h1>';
        $html .= '<p>Email: ' . $request->input('email') . '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>Phone: ' . $request->input('phone') . '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>Address: ' . $request->input('address') . '</p>';

        // Create a new PDF instance
        $pdf = new PDF();

        // Generate the PDF from the HTML
        $pdf->loadHTML($html);

        // Return the PDF as a download
        return $pdf->download('resume.pdf');
    }
}
```

But now I get this error:

**Too few arguments to function Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\resume-maker\app\Http\Controllers\ResumeController.php on line 21 and exactly 4 expected**

I asked ChatGPT this error and it says change the code to this:

```
public function generate(Request $request)
    {
        // Generate HTML for the resume using the form data
        $html = '<h1>' . $request->input('name') . '</h1>';
        $html .= '<p>Email: ' . $request->input('email') . '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>Phone: ' . $request->input('phone') . '</p>';
        $html .= '<p>Address: ' . $request->input('address') . '</p>';

        // Create a new PDF instance with the required arguments
        $pdf = new PDF([
            'font_path' => base_path('resources/fonts/'),
            'font_family' => 'Roboto',
            'margin_top' => 0,
            'margin_left' => 0,
            'margin_right' => 0,
            'margin_bottom' => 0,
            'default_font_size' => 12,
            'default_font' => 'Roboto'
        ], 'A4', 'portrait', true);

        // Generate the PDF from the HTML
        $pdf->loadHTML($html);

        // Return the PDF as a download
        return $pdf->download('resume.pdf');
    }
```

But now I get this error:

**Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct(): Argument #1 ($dompdf) must be of type Dompdf\Dompdf, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\resume-maker\app\Http\Controllers\ResumeController.php on line 30**

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue and produce pdf file properly?

Note that my dompdf version is `"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use Facade instead of instantiating class.

import

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf as PDF;
```

then in code

```
// Generate the PDF from the HTML
$pdf=PDF::loadHTML($html);

// Return the PDF as a download
return $pdf->download('resume.pdf');
```

Ref: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf